# How to fire text message to particular mobile numbers when my device enters into geofence specified?

Tags: gps, automation

I want to track a vehicle fleet. Whenever the device enters into the specified geofence, it should fire a text message to the specified mobile numbers, so that they will get notified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a specific application to do this: it can be done with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Use the [AutoLocation plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autolocation) to set up a geofence event. In Tasker, create a profile "enter depot" (or whatever the area is), where the *event* is entering the geofence you defined, and the *task* is to send an SMS. (You can find "Send SMS" under the "Phone" action category.)

With the [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory) feature, you can also [export an app](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/appcreation.html) of this configuration, to easily install on multiple devices.

I'm sure you can set up something similar using Automate or another automation app. I just know how to do it with Tasker because that's what I use.